# Issue in process builder

Tags: process-builder, automation, process, process-automation, builder

I am working on a process builder on the object Grant which works while it is created/edited.The criteria to be met are (Stage=A AND Substage=B) OR (Stage=C AND Substage=null).If these conditions are met a date field which I have created have to be populated with todays date.

This is working while creating the grant and the date is populated.While updating consider I have a grant record created with Stage=A AND Substage=B.So The date field is with today's date.Now If i removed the date field and change it to blank and automatically change the substage to E or any value not present in the process builder conditions and save.If I again change the substage to B I am not getting the date value.

I also tried this with all the conditions not meeting the requirement to meeting all the requirement.At this point it is working.
But while keeping any of the fields same and another different and then changing to both meeting the requirement I cannot get the value.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you add a snapshot of the PB entry conditions, this will help people here understand better what might be going on?

Comment: @SachinHooda Yes Added

Comment: I doubt it is something related to the Process builder you mentioned here. It might be some other automation, probably an after-update Flow that updates the Review Date. You may want to look at debug logs to see what's exactly happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I doubt it is something related to the Process builder you mentioned here. It might be some other automation, probably an after-update Flow that updates the Review Date. You may want to look at debug logs to see what's exactly happening. See [Order of Execution](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_order_of_execution.htm)

Keep debug Log level to fine or finest for Workflow, Database & System.